# How to search in a single channel?

Tags: search, slack

When I use the search box built into Slack, I'm presented with a choice of what channels to include in the search, but the most limited choice I can make there is "Include: only messages from channels that I have opened". This is very inconvenient considering 99% of times I know very well which channel (or "DM channel") the message is in (usually it's a "DM channel").

**How do I search in a single channel (which may be a "DM channel")?**

**Note:** I don't know if there's an official name for "DM channels", I use this term to mean "the space where I exchange messages with a *single* person".

Answer (score 38):

Found the answer in [the Slack docs](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202528808-Search-for-messages-and-files).

The solution is to add the text `in:someChannel` or `in:someUser` to your search query.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I'm searching for works which I can _literally see in the channel_, and the search results are coming up empty

Comment: Same here, I got no results when I specify channel

Answer (score 3):

The channel name should be preceded by the channel type character.

EG;

To find messages with text *Hello* in the personal channel *Jake* the search would be `Hello in:@Jake`

To find messages with text *Hello* in the group channel *General* the search would be `Hello in:#General`

Answer (score 2):

When you are in the channel in which you want to search, just use Command+F on MacOS or Ctrl+F on other operating systems. It will pre-populate the search field with `in:#<channel-name>` for you.

Otherwise, you need to type it manually, which also works but less convenient.

Comment: I use slack in chrome. Ctrl+F open the search popup of the web browser. It would be cool to have a quick way to search in the current channel only.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can change that in the **Preferences** > **Advanced** > **"Ctrl F starts a Slack search"** and it will override the normal browser search behavior.