# How to search in the current slack channel?

Tags: slack

If I am in slack channel "#foo" I want a quick way to search in this channel.

I know that I can search and then enter "in:foo" but this is cumbersome.

Is there a quick way to search in the current channel (without typing in the name of the channel)?

I use the web version of slack.

Related: [How to search in a single channel?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103425/how-to-search-in-a-single-channel)

Comment: I think you answered this yourself :), in:#channel_name is the best way if you are a fan of typing or clicking on the "Shared in" on the right would be the next best thing in the search popup.

Comment: @Joe I can type fast. But it is best, if I don't need to type at all. I don't want to type the channel name again, since this context information is already provided by the focus of the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Focus on the channel's textbox (where you write your messages) and press ctrl + F (or cmd + F if you're using a Mac) and a search bar will appear without you needing to type anything else but your search query. The rest is pre-filled.

In order for this to work you will have to be on the channel you want to search in and you need to have clicked on the message text box before pressing ctrl + F.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I use the web version of slack. If I hit ctrl-f, then the usual "search in page" pop-up of the browser opens. Your answer does not work for me. But I am unsure what you mean with "click ctrl + F", since I type with the keyboard, and click with the mouse...

Comment: Hmm this works in the standalone version of Slack. I'm not sure about the web version. (I meant to say press, not click. Updating..)

Answer (score 1):

Entering the search modifier "in:channel name" works as already posted.  However to save typing, click on Details then Find.  This inserts the modifier with the channel name filled in.